# Same query from same application to different database get mixed up

Tags: sql-server-2012, c#, query-cache

We have an application MVC C#.
The same application is used for several users.
On logging in a session is created to know which company the user is from depending on that query should go to a different database.

For each company there is a seperate database. 
Ever so often, we get the results back from the wrong database. (in webbrowser)

When refreshing the results will be just fine ( from correct databse ).

All in all this is 'some sort' of caching issue. The caching can not be at userlevel since the user has never accessed the other database before.

So chaching has to be serverside.

**The question is, is there some way SQL-server caches SQL results OVER databases? And thus returning data from another database?**

*Or is it more likely there is some caching done in the http requests on IIS?*

Thanks for any advice in the right direction.

Comment: I've never seen/heard SQL Server cache query results over databases and serve wrong information. This is most likely on your Web Browser/app side caching the content, as you say, when refreshed it displays correct.

Comment: ok, thank you for aknowledging this. It is what I would expect aswell..

Comment: Try forcing (In developer tools from the browser) to always clear browser cache.